# Piping input into ipython

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pipe, ipython

I wanted to know if it was possible to pipe input from a file to a python program run in ipython.

As in: "cat input | run dum.py" or "run dum.py < input"

Neither of these work.

Edit: "cat input | python dum.py" works but it doesn't load all the variables into the ipython session, like "run dum.py" does.

Comment: Are you issuing these commands from within an interactive `ipython` session?  What does `dum.py` do? (more or less).

Comment: Gives us a [MCVE]

Comment: `!!cat ...` captures the `stdout` (e..g print) from the piped command, but does not capture any variables created by `dum.py`.  In contrast `run dum.py` does leave variables created by `dum` in the `ipython` workspace.  `run` is different from issuing a system command.  But I can't make the `<` work, and I don't see anything in the `%run` docs about it.  In other words `%run` does not behave like a shell.

Comment: But if `dum.py` reads the commandline (`sys.argv`), you could pass the `input` file name to it, and read the file that way.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to run these in the interactive ipython session. 
"dum.py" is a general program which takes some string input and displays a string output. I want this input to come from a file, and I want to pipe the file into the python/run command in the interactive ipython session.

Ill try the sys.argv

Comment: When you use "run dum.py < input", the `sys.argv` will be `['dum.py', '<', 'input']`, a list of the strings following 'run'.  The `<` is just passed as part of the commandline.  It is not interpreted as a shell redirection command.